# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I'm learning about Appium and python but I can't run my 1st code, I've done installing the Appium, Python and Selenium.

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "12",
  "deviceName": "OP56F5",
  "automationName": "UIAutomator2",
  "appPackage": "com.coloros.calculator",
  "appActivity": "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

I'm trying to open the calculator of my android device with that code but always throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\Python Testing\mobile\sessions_appium_calc.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 229, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in __init__
    capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'
```

Please help to solve that thx

Answer (score 0):

looks like you didn't import related module. Add following code at the top of your script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
```

Comment: thanks for the help but the console throws the same error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'